# How do I go about contructing the function in the context below?

Tags: probability

[image]

---

In (a), I think the first answer is $  \frac{\theta}{2}$, and we should double the sample mean to get $\theta$.

In (b), I think the sample maximum would vary according to a normal distribution.

The pdf of $ X $ is $f_x(x) = \frac{1}{\theta}$ ; the cdf of $ X $ is $F_x(x) = \frac{x}{\theta}$

From here, I am stuck. Please help me about (c) and (d).

Comment: PLease include your own attempts. What is the cdf of $X$? What is the definition of cdf of the sample maximum? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @NCh I  edited  under your advice.

Comment: you thought pdf and cdf of the distribution of population, not of sample mean